# Selenium Edge web Driver can't find element in iframe nested

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to make an automation in a website we have in my work.
I have an issue when i'm trying to find a element.
The element is into 3 iframes. The second and the third iframe have the same id.
I'm trying to find an element in the third one.

here 's the code of the web page:

```
<iframe frameborder="0" id="content" name="content" onload="checkMemory()" width="100%" height="100%" src="emxNavigatorContentLoad.jsp?ticket=ST-307153-LWk2GNizVKjxhyGRQ3Ib-cas&amp;collabSpace=KLA+Collabspace"></iframe>
```

so i entered to this iframe:

```
driver.SwitchTo().Frame("content");
driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
```

here the second and third iframe:

```
<iframe id="tvcTabs0contentFrame" name="detailsDisplay" configname="tvcTabs0_" frameborder="0" border="0" scrolling="auto" width="100%" height="100%" onload="tvcTabPage_pageLoaded('tvcTabs0')" src="https:.../tvc/core/tvcBlank.jsp"></iframe>

<iframe id="tvcTabs0contentFrame" name="tvcTabs0contentFrame" configname="tvcTabs0_" frameborder="0" border="0" scrolling="auto" width="100%" height="100%" onload="tvcTabPage_pageLoaded('tvcTabs0')" src="https:.../tvc/core/tvcBlank.jsp"></iframe>
```

here's the element i'm trying to find:

```
<td tvc-id="tvc-forminput" class="inputField">0808030-000<input type="hidden" id="f44" name="f44" value="0808030-000">
```

here's my code:

```
driver.SwitchTo().Frame(driver.FindElement(By.Name("tvcTabs0contentFrame")));
driver.SwitchTo().Frame(driver.FindElement(By.Name("tvcTabs0contentFrame")));
var txt2 = driver.FindElement(By.Id("tvc-forminput"));
```

i want to target the text: "0808030-000"
but it can't find the id: tvc-forminput

Thank you

Comment: the second frame's name attribute shows: name="detailsDisplay"  (you should probably also remove the implicit wait and use explicit wait of frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt: https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(org.openqa.selenium.By)  (You might also want to tell them about the duplicate IDs there... those should be unique)